# cannot get the right page in express.js

Tags: node.js, express

In express.js 4.2.0 I have the following routes

```
var photos = require('./routes/photos');
app.use('/', photos.list);
app.get('/upload', photos.form);
```

This is the `photos.js` which contains some pics and the functions `list` and `form`.

```
var photos = [];

photos.push({
    name: 'Node.js Logo',
    path: 'http://nodejs.org/images/logos/nodejs-green.png'
});

photos.push({
    name: 'Ryan Speaking',
    path: 'http://nodejs.org/images/ryan-speaker.jpg'
});

exports.list = function(req, res){
    res.render('photos', {
        title: 'Photos',
        photos: photos
    });
};

exports.form = function(req, res){
    res.render('photos/upload', {
        title: 'Photo upload'
    });
};
```

`index.ejs` and `upload.ejs` are in `views > photos` directory. Now when I start the server I get 2 warns, "No repository field" and "No readme data" about the package.json.

I hit `http://localhost:4500` I see `GET / 200` and everything works fine. I hit `http://localhost:4500/upload` I see `GET /upload 200` or `GET /upload 304` if I refresh. But the browser still renders the index page. I dont get any other errors.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"No repository field" and "No readme data" just means your package.json isn't complete, and npm wants you to add URLs for where the package is stored and documented.

Then, you probably want the following:

```
var photos = require('./routes/photos');
app.get('/', photos.list); // <--------------- `get` instead of `use`
app.get('/upload', photos.form);
```

[`app.use`](http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.use) is for middleware, which is *not* what `list` and `form` implement.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. But why the default setup of express uses `use` instead of `get` to render a simple `index` file?

Comment: `get` here refers to the HTTP GET verb. You can also have `app.post()` for POST requests, `app.delete` for DELETEs, etc. So `use` was a reasonable name for specifying middleware. You could make the code in `photos.js` implement a router middleware and then `use` that: see http://expressjs.com/guide/routing.html#express-router